# How to translate 符号被异化的环境中?

Tags: translation

I have difficulty with the following text, which ideally, I want to translate to German, but correctly understanding it’s English equivalent would already be enough. The problem is mostly with the highlighted passage:

> 每一个新疆人都是中国这幅画面上的一抹颜色。他们离开家乡，在北京、上海、广州等大中城市工作生活，在社会发展中靠自己的知识和能力创造着自己的生活，也为社会创造了很多价值，**在新疆这个符号被异化的社会环境中**，他们没有选择逃避或极端，而是通过个人的努力和奋斗，继续热爱生活，坚守着自己的专业和岗位，收获着一定意义的成功。《我从新疆来》里每一个人都在努力的与这个社会和时代融合，与不同的民族和文化融合，都在传达我们对于奋斗着的普通人的尊重

Since my dictionaries classify 符号 as a noun, I am inclined to translate it as one of the following:

> In Xinjiang, this social environment where signs are alienated / In Xinjiang, this social environment where symbols are alienated

Now, my native speaker friend seems to interpret 符号 as a verb, explaining:

> 新疆——现在已经成为一个被异化的符号

Then it would mean that Xinjiang itself had become a mark/symbol of alienation. Also, she objects to „symbol“, which makes the German translation difficult (I find „Zeichen der Entfremdung“ very unclear).

Comment: I believe 异化 is the verb, not 符号

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 在新疆这个符号被异化的社会环境中

The writing is a bit confusing per se. But based on context, 新疆 and 这个符号 are in apposition and they are alienated in the social environment.

The whole thing is a prepositional phrase 在社会环境中. 新疆这个符号被异化的 is an attributive phrase modifying 社会环境.

The translation might be: *in a social environment, where Xinjiang as a sign/symbol/mark has been alienated.*

Not sure my translation is accurate though considering my knowledge about English.

Comment: How would you interpret „sign“? Is it close to „symbol“?

Comment: @Ludi Not sure about the nuance between sign and symbol in English. Probably it's mark, symbol,etc.

Answer (score 6):

I would translate it to "In a society where Xinjiang as a symbol has been alienated"

Regarding the meaning of `符号`. I think symbol is better. Because the what the paragraph is trying to convey is that Xinjiang people, in spite of their hometown being used  as a *symbol* for some political issues, including but not limited to terrorism, extremism, etc. They themselves still, like other people, yearn for a better life. And, in the process, enlightens cities like BJ, SH, and ultimately, China as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

I believe "新疆这个符号" should be a whole as the subject

在**新疆这个符号**被异化的社会环境中=
In a social environment where the sign of Xinjiang is alienated.

Comment: I think you are correct, since the protagonists are outside Xinjiang. How should we interpret „sign of Xinjiang“?

Comment: This is an abstract concept, roughly means the impression of 新疆.

Comment: In the social environment that people's impression of Xinjiang are biased.

Answer (score 1):

Moin!

被异化: be "differentized": regarded as not the same as the rest of, in this case, China

每一个新疆人都是中国这幅画面上的一抹颜色。

Everyone from Xinjiang is a burst of colour on the Chinese landscape.

Jeder Mensch aus Xinjiang ist ein bunter Farbfleck in der chinesischen Landschaft.

他们离开家乡，

They left their hometowns,

Sie verließen ihre Heimate,

在北京、上海、广州等大中城市工作生活，

to live and work in big and medium-sized cities like Beijing, Shanghai, Canton etc.,

um in Groß- und Mittelgroßstädten wie Peking, Shanghai und Kanton zu leben und zu arbeiten,

在社会发展中靠自己的知识和能力创造着自己的生活，

as far as their social development is concerned, they rely on their own knowledge and capabilities to create their own way of life,

In Bezug auf ihre soziale Entwicklung, verlassen sie sich auf ihr eigenes Wissen und Fähigkeiten, um ihre eigene Lebensart zu gestalten,

也为社会创造了很多价值，

they also create a lot of value for society as a whole.

sie schaffen auch viel Wert für die Gesellschaft als Ganzes.

在新疆这个符号被异化的社会环境中，

In Xinjiang, this symbol (for terrorism) of being "outside of the normal Chinese social environment",

In Xinjiang, ein Symbol (für den Terrorismus) angeguckt als "ausserhalb der normalen chinesischen Gesellschft",

他们没有选择逃避或极端，

they chose neither escape nor extremism,

wählten sie weder die Flucht noch den Extremismus,

而是通过个人的努力和奋斗，

rather, by means of individual effort und struggle,

sondern, durch individuelle Anstrengung und persönliches Bemühen,

继续热爱生活，

they continue to cherish life,

schätzen und achten sie weiterhin das Leben (anderer),

坚守着自己的专业和岗位，

hold fast to their profession and job,

halten sie sich fest an Beruf und Arbeit,

收获着一定意义的成功。

thereby reaping a certain sense of success.

und dadurch erlangen sie einen bestimmten Erfolgssinn.

《我从新疆来》里

(Ich komme aus Xinjiang)

每一个人都在努力的与这个社会和时代融合，

Every person is trying hard to fit in with this society and time,

Jeder Mensch versucht, sich in diese Gesellschaft und Zeit einzufügen,

与不同的民族和文化融合，

to mix with different ethnic groups and cultures,

sich mit verschiedenen ethnischen Gruppen und Kulturen zu integrieren,

都在传达我们对于奋斗着的普通人的尊重。

we all convey our respect towards the ordinary people striving in this respect.

wir alle bringen den einfachen Menschen, die sich in dieser Hinsicht bemühen, unseren Respekt entgegen.

Answer (score 0):

in the social environment of the symbol 'Xinjiang' which is alienated
in the social environment of the alienated symbol 'Xinjiang'

you may ommit the bold text in this case:
对于张三**这个人**而言: for Zhang San
you may not ommit the bold text in this case:
对于张三**这个**固执的**人**而言: for the stubborn Zhang San
you may speak like this alternatively:
对于固执的张三而言: for the stubborn Zhang San

similarly, you may ommit the bold text in this case:
在新疆**这个**社会环境中
在新疆社会环境中
also, you may speak like this alternatively:
在新疆**这个**符号被异化的社会环境中
在符号被异化的新疆社会环境中

Answer (score 0):

The raw text is kind of confusing or inaccurate.
According to context, it should be:

> 在新疆作为一个符号被异化了的社会环境中

> In the society which has alienated Xinjiang as a symbol